# Power series $x f''(x) + f'(x) + xf(x) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions, power-series

> Find a power series with radius of convergence $R = \infty$ such that $$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}x^{n}$$ satisfies $$x f''(x) + f'(x) + xf(x)= 0, \forall \mbox{ } x \in \mathbb R.$$

How should I go about solving this question? I have a gut feeling that it has to do with trig functions because I know that the terms in each power series have to cancel out in the resulting addition to satisfy the equation.

Comment: Write $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$ with a power series, rewrite terms in order to transform the LHS into a power series, then identity coefficients.

Comment: If you just need one solution then $a_n=0$ for all $n$ should work... :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{lcr}
f(x) &=& a_0 +& a_1x +& a_2x^2 +\cdots+& a_nx^n +\cdots \\[2ex]
f'(x) &=& a_1 +& 2a_2x +& 3a_3x^2 +\cdots+& (n+1)a_{n+1}x^n +\cdots \\
xf''(x) &=& & 1\cdot2a_2 x +& 2\cdot3a_3x^2 +\cdots+& n(n+1)a_{n+1}x^n +\cdots \\
xf(x) &=& & a_0x +& a_1x^2 +\cdots+& a_{n-1}x^n +\cdots \\
\hline
0 &=& a_1 +& (4a_2+a_0)x +& (9a_3+a_1)x^2 +\cdots+& ((n+1)^2a_{n+1}+a_{n-1})x^n +\cdots
\end{array}$$

In order for the bottom row to be $0$, each of the coefficients must be, so we have $a_1=0$ and $(n+1)^2a_{n+1}+a_{n-1}=0$ for $n\ge 1$. Setting $k=n+1$ the latter equation becomes
$$a_k = -\frac{a_{k-2}}{k^2} \qquad\text{for }k\ge 2$$
So all of the *odd* coefficients must be zero, and the *even* coefficients all determine each other. Every solution must be a multiple of the one with $a_0=1$, where we have
$$a_{2m} = \frac{(-1)^m}{2^2\cdot 4^2\cdot 6^2 \cdots (2m)^2} = \frac{(-1)^m}{m!^2 2^{2m}}$$
I trust you can verify the convergence radius of this one yourself.

(This solution is the [Bessel function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) $J_0$).

Comment: I think you have a typo in the recursion formula for $a_k$.

Comment: @David: Thanks. Signs are annoying; one should always work in characteristic 2 where ${-}={+}$.

Comment: ....and it you want to fit a straight line, the obtain only two data points.  Also, if reproducibility may be a problem, then perform the test only once.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Did you intend for that comment to go somewhere else?

Comment: @HenningMakholm : No.  It seemed in the same spirit as you "$+=-$" comment.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Ah, sorry. Went over my head.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.